# c# Get Altitude at position

Tags: c#, latitude-longitude, altitude

I need to get the altitude of a latitude and longitude position (ground altitude).

I haven't found anything able to do this.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use Shuttle Radar Topography Mission (SRTM) data files, which may be obtained through this URL: https://firmware.ardupilot.org/SRTM/
This data is from:
http://scenery.flightgear.org/geodata/fgx/elevation/srtm_filled/
(many thanks to flightgear and to the USGS for providing this data set)

for c# dll library see : https://github.com/javadsadi/SRTM

Answer (score 2):

The USGS (US Geological Survey) has an API for this as well that includes a WSDL. http://cumulus.cr.usgs.gov/service_description_elevation.php

Comment: I get: The specified URL cannot be found.

Answer (score 1):

Use BING MAP SDK with spatial services (REST)
[More info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877180.aspx)

Comment: I like this because they have documented c# code. However, they require licensing through emailing them (quite annoying). I've submitted a request and if no other option works well and this one works after getting a license, I will give you a +1 and answer credit.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [Google Elevation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/#ElevationRequests). From C#, use a `WebClient` to request URLs such as: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=39.7391536,-104.9847034|36.455556,-116.866667&sensor=true

Or download [the .Net library](http://gmaps.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Hi, I have some issues with the the library. I get the following error: "System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request." Since there is no documentation, I can't figure out if I am formatting my request properly. I am using latitude, longitude as the format. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [The Google Elevation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/)